# Как убрать отступы у элемента выступающий в html странице как заголовок?

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста! Как убрать отступы у элемента выступающий в html странице как заголовок? Мне нужно чтобы шапка странички была вся одним цветом но по бокам(left,right.) и сверху(top)виден цвет тела(body) страницы. с помощью margin: 0; padding: 0; не получается. Может есть другой способ? Помогите!

```
HTML:
    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <p><a href=""><img src="img/avto.jpg" /></a></p>
    </div>

CSS:
    body {background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: cursive, Verdana, Arial, sana-serif; }

   #header {background: #000000; height: 100px;   margin: 0; padding: 0; }
   #header img { position: relative; left: 100px; top: 20px; }
```

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/216642#216645 вот ваш пример http://plnkr.co/edit/SF40JjCAv6GkyeKW89PG?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте reset.css - [ссылка](http://www.xiper.net/collect/services/build-reset-css.html)

Вы задаете сброс отступов для **#header**, а нужно для **body**, **html**

И вообще, возьмите себе за правило использовать сброс стилей - это хорошая практика!

Удачи

Comment: на эту тему есть разные мнения (по поводу хорошая ли это практика) http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/no_css_reset/

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, с удовольствием почитаю.